# "Capacity of X" vs "X capacity"

Tags: technical

I am a technical person.

Here is just an example, but this approach can be used in many situations (including other hardware components).

I want to specify that my hard disk drive (HDD) can store 100 GB of information.

How can I say this ?

- HDD of 100 GB capacity

or

- HDD having a capacity of 100 GB

Comment: The normal way is to say a "100 GB hard drive". You typically (idiomatically) don't need to explicitly use the word "capacity" in these situations.

Comment: The place where you might use _capacity_ is in a list of features. There you might write _Capacity: 100 GB_.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them make sense and are grammatically correct, but stylistically, the most concise way to say it would be "a 100-GB HDD." Note that hyphens are used when compound adjectives come before a noun.

Comment: Actually, when writing quantities with measurement units, hyphens should not be used, even when quantity is part of a compound noun. So, especially in technical writing, you should write "a 100 GB HDD" or, for example, "a 2 m long bar". For a reference see e.g. [NIST guide to SI](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/sec07.html), Sec. 7.2.

Comment: In scientific writing, perhaps, but in everyday writing, the hyphen would be necessary. Compare "a two-mile road" or "a ten-pound weight."

Comment: The OP stated that he is a technical person and the question is tagged as "technical". So, it is better to report technically correct information.